# Behavior of Pa_GetDeviceInfo() and PaAsio_GetAvailableBufferSizes()

Tags: pyaudio, portaudio, asio

I'm building a simple application using portaudio, but there is something I can't quite explain when it comes to ASIO drivers, and to the behavior of `Pa_GetDeviceInfo()` and `PaAsio_GetAvailableBufferSizes()`

Let's say I use an external application to record audio from my ASIO device at 48 kHz.
At this point if I run the "pa_devs" example that ships with portaudio, I get the below:

```
[ Default ASIO Input, Default ASIO Output ]
Name                        = xxx
Host API                    = ASIO
Max inputs = 8, Max outputs = 8
Default low input latency   =   0.0196
Default low output latency  =   0.0196
Default high input latency  =   0.0196
Default high output latency =   0.0196
ASIO minimum buffer size    = 864
ASIO maximum buffer size    = 864
ASIO preferred buffer size  = 864
ASIO buffer granularity     = 0
Default sample rate         = 44100.00
```

Now if I make a second recording at 192 kHz, and subsequently run "pa_devs" again, I get this:

```
[ Default ASIO Input, Default ASIO Output ]
Name                        = xxx
Host API                    = ASIO
Max inputs = 8, Max outputs = 8
Default low input latency   =   0.0784
Default low output latency  =   0.0784
Default high input latency  =   0.0784
Default high output latency =   0.0784
ASIO minimum buffer size    = 3456
ASIO maximum buffer size    = 3456
ASIO preferred buffer size  = 3456
ASIO buffer granularity     = 0
Default sample rate         = 44100.00
```

So what seems to be happening is that the buffer size is automatically adjusted based on the sample rate, to maintain a fixed latency in absolute terms:

864/48000 = 3456/192000 = 18 ms

Now here is the real question. As opposed to "pa_devs", my own application doesn't start and stop between recordings, but is constantly running on the side.
However, if between recordings my app calls `Pa_GetDeviceInfo()` and `PaAsio_GetAvailableBufferSizes()` then I invariably get the same latencies and the same ASIO buffer sizes. Basically it doesn't seem to see that the external recording application has changed the sample rate between successive calls. Any ideas what can be causing that ?

**[edit]**: using pyaudio builds from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio) (with ASIO support) as a different observation mechanism, I find that executing `pyaudio.PyAudio().get_device_info_by_index(N)` also invariably returns the same answer, even though the sample rate has been changed (which I can also monitor on the ASIO control panel)

Yet as a different observation mechanism, I have an Audio Precision box. On the ASIO connector settings, it **instantly** reflects any changes of sample rate and changes of buffer sizes as soon as recording starts on the external application. How come pyaudio and my own app do not get notified of changes too ?

Comment: This doesn't only affects ASIO devices. It also affects other types actually. For example if a WASAPI device default sample rates is changed from the Windows audio control panel, then `Pa_GetDeviceInfo()` won't reflect the changes....

Answer (score 0):

At least now I think I understand the root cause of the problem. I'm not too sure if that's a bug or a design intent.

When the parameters of devices get changed externally (e.g. current sample rate or default sample rate), portaudio won't reflect these changes (in terms of sample rate but also in terms of buffer sizes and latencies) as long as **all** previous calls to `Pa_Initialize()` have not been closed by a `Pa_Terminate()` and that `Pa_Initialize()` is eventually called again.

So if an app calls `Pa_Initialize()` at startup, it will get the same replies from all subsequent calls to `Pa_GetDeviceInfo()` and `PaAsio_GetAvailableBufferSizes()`, even if devices properties are changed externally in the meantime.

Rather, it seems an app should always call `Pa_Initialize()` and `Pa_Terminate()` in pairs every time it wants to do anything, be it as simple as `Pa_GetDeviceInfo()`. It seems to raise further questions:

1. what about `pyaudio` ? it exposes `terminate()` but doesn't expose `initialize()`. I haven't found a way to force an update of devices properties. Even `reload(pyaudio)` doesn't do the trick.
2. What about apps that are concurrently running and that load the same shared portaudio library ? If they make interleaved calls to `Pa_Initialize()` and `Pa_Terminate()`, they presumably won't get correct values ?

Comment: With the `pyaudio` module, a call to `pyaudio.PyAudio()` should initialize PortAudio, see https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/#example-callback-mode-audio-i-o. And to shamelessly plug my own PortAudio wrapper: the `sounddevice` module has the `_initialize()` and `_terminate()` functions, see https://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/0.4.1/api/expert-mode.html.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to `sounddevice`, I'll have a look ! And you're right that `pyaudio.PyAudio()` initializes PortAudio but this not exactly the issue.
The fundamental question is: when should `Pa_Initialize()` and `Pa_Terminate()` be called ? I was under the impression that an app could call `Pa_Initialize()` at start-up and `Pa_Terminate()` at exit, and could do anything it wants in between. My experiments suggest it is not the case: `Pa_GetDeviceInfo()` seem to be valid only if it immediately follows `Pa_Initialize()` but not if devices were altered since the last `Pa_Initialize()` call

Comment: Yes, that's true. There have been some efforts in the past to mitigate this (search for "PortAudio hotplug"), but AFAIK, none of those have made it into PortAudio proper so far. In the meantime, you'll have to terminate and re-initialize every time the devices change.